# Laravel wrong route redirection resulting in a 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

In my Laravel app, I get a **404** error and I can't figure out why. The route correctly appears in `artisan route:list`. I'm using route groupping and prefixes. Laravel debug output shows a different URI than expected. It seems that the `books.archives` route redirects to the `book.display` route. I just don't get it.

Here is an extract of my web.php :

```php
    // Books
    Route::prefix('books')->name('books')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', [BooksController::class, 'list']);
        Route::get('/create', [BooksController::class, 'create'])->name('.create');
        Route::post('/', [BooksController::class, 'store'])->name('.store');
        Route::get('/edit/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'edit'])->name('.edit');
        Route::patch('/edit/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'update'])->name('.update');
        Route::get('/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'display'])->name('.display');
        Route::post('/delete/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'delete'])->name('.delete');
        
        Route::prefix('archives')->name('.archives')->group(function() {
            Route::get('/', [BooksController::class, 'archived']);
            Route::get('/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'archive'])->name('.store');
            Route::post('/delete/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'delete'])->name('.delete');
            Route::post('/delete/all', [BooksController::class, 'deleteAll'])->name('.delete.all');
            Route::get('/restore/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'restore'])->name('.restore');
        });
    });
```

The `artisan route:list` output :

```
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books                                                     | books                       | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@list                               | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | POST     | dashboard/books                                                     | books.store                 | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@store                              | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/archives                                            | books.archives              | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@archived                           | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | POST     | dashboard/books/archives/delete/all                                 | books.archives.delete.all   | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@deleteAll                          | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | POST     | dashboard/books/archives/delete/{bookInfo}                          | books.archives.delete       | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@delete                             | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/archives/restore/{id}                               | books.archives.restore      | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@restore                            | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/archives/{bookInfo}                                 | books.archives.store        | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@archive                            | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/create                                              | books.create                | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@create                             | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | POST     | dashboard/books/delete/{id}                                         | books.delete                | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@delete                             | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/edit/{bookInfo}                                     | books.edit                  | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@edit                               | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | PATCH    | dashboard/books/edit/{bookInfo}                                     | books.update                | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@update                             | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | DELETE   | dashboard/books/variations/delete/{book}                            | variations.delete           | App\Http\Controllers\VariationsController@delete                        | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/variations/edit/{book}                              | variations.edit             | App\Http\Controllers\VariationsController@edit                          | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | PATCH    | dashboard/books/variations/edit/{book}                              | variations.update           | App\Http\Controllers\VariationsController@update                        | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | POST     | dashboard/books/variations/{bookInfo}/add                           | variations.store            | App\Http\Controllers\VariationsController@store                         | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/variations/{bookInfo}/add                           | variations.create           | App\Http\Controllers\VariationsController@create                        | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/books/{bookInfo}                                          | books.display               | App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@display                            | web                                                |
|        |          |                                                                     |                             |                                                                         | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
```

The controller :

```
    public function archived() {
        $bookInfos = BookInfo::onlyTrashed()->get();
        $archived = $bookInfos->count();
        return view('books.archived', compact('bookInfos', 'archived'));
    }
```

The debug output (from the page */dashboard/books/archives*) :

[image: Route debug output]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the path matches both "books.display" and "books.archives.archived" routes, maybe it is taking the first of them. Try putting the "archive" group of routes before the "book" routes:

```
    // Books
Route::prefix('books')->name('books')->group(function() {

    Route::prefix('archives')->name('.archives')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', [BooksController::class, 'archived']);
        Route::get('/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'archive'])->name('.store');
        Route::post('/delete/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'delete'])->name('.delete');
        Route::post('/delete/all', [BooksController::class, 'deleteAll'])->name('.delete.all');
        Route::get('/restore/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'restore'])->name('.restore');
    });

    Route::get('/', [BooksController::class, 'list']);
    Route::get('/create', [BooksController::class, 'create'])->name('.create');
    Route::post('/', [BooksController::class, 'store'])->name('.store');
    Route::get('/edit/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'edit'])->name('.edit');
    Route::patch('/edit/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'update'])->name('.update');
    Route::get('/{bookInfo}', [BooksController::class, 'display'])->name('.display');
    Route::post('/delete/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'delete'])->name('.delete');
    
    
});
```

Comment: That was my first thaught too, but now I'm realising that it didn't work then because I had forgot to clear the route cache. Rookie mistake... Now it works of course. Thanks for pointing that out again !